# Using Drawing Cache to Animate WebView. Am I doing this right?

Tags: android, android-animation

So I'm doing a flip card animation with a webview that takes up about 80% of the screen.
[Flip Card Animation Tutorial](http://developer.android.com/training/animation/cardflip.html)

Ever since I swapped to a WebView from a TextView using Spannables, the animation was looking a bit off, so I slowed it down, and I noticed that as the 3d flip occured, lines would begin to vanish from the bottom and top of the WebView as the animation proceeded. It bothered me, and so I wanted to fix it.

**My Solution**: I added an ImageView that when the animation starts, I pull the drawing cache bitmap from the WebView, make the WebView invisible, set the WebView drawing cache Bitmap to the ImageView, and show the ImageView.

**With the creation of the webview:**

```
mWebView.setAnimationCacheEnabled(false);
mWebView.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
mWebView.setDrawingCacheQuality(View.DRAWING_CACHE_QUALITY_AUTO);
```

**On Start Animation and on Stop:**

```
public void setIsAnimating(boolean isAnimating) {
    mIsAnimating = isAnimating;
    if (mIsAnimating) {
        Bitmap webCache = mWebView.getDrawingCache();
        mCachedView.setImageBitmap(webCache);

        mCachedView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        mWebView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        mProgressView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    } else {
        mWebView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        mCachedView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        mProgressView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
}
```

This solution seems to work well, however I can see a slight 100 ms or so lag now before the animation actually takes. Is this how the drawing cache works? How is it meant to be used? If not like this, then how? I haven't been able to find many examples  / explanations working with the drawing cache.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with WebView capturePicture() method:

```
Picture picture = view.capturePicture();

Bitmap  b = Bitmap.createBitmap( picture.getWidth(),picture.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
```

Comment: capturePicture is deprecated, you could use "draw"  instead.